# Where does the sky's blueness come from; at what altitudes is it being produced?

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-optics

[Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) (mostly) results in a blue sky ([Diffuse_sky_radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_sky_radiation)) as seen from Earth's surface. Go up in a plane to cruise altitude and the sky gets noticeably blue-er, and then darker.

The scale height of the Earth's atmosphere is roughly 8 kilometers, which means that half of Earth's atmosphere's mass is below about 5.5 km, again roughly.

**Question:** Does half of a blue sky's blue light come from this lower 5.5 kilometers as well, or does the effect vary with density such that a disproportionate amount is coming from higher altitudes?

Origin of this question is from comments below [@Ingolifs' answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35306/12102) to *Puzzler: help understanding these amazing Curiosity eclipse GIFs*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take your question as the question about *first* scattering event, ignoring all the subsequent ones (because they bounce light rays between the top and bottom halves of atmosphere). Also, I'm assuming daylight conditions, like 45° solar elevation.

Let's look at a simulation I did using my [CalcMySky](https://github.com/10110111/CalcMySky) software. Here's how the first scattering order luminance looks in equirectangular projection for an observer at $1\,\mathrm m$ altitude:

[image]

Now the same for $5500\,\mathrm m$ altitude:

[image]

For completeness, let's also see the same from $25\,500\,\mathrm m$:

[image]

So, you're basically right: $5500\,\mathrm m$ is roughly the altitude where first scattering contribution is the same from below and from above the observer.

Comment: Oh this is very cool, thanks! Additional links to Eric Bruneton, Fabrice Neyret
 (2008) *Precomputed Atmospheric Scattering*  [1](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00288758/en), [2](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00288758), [3](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-8659.2008.01245.x) also potentially helpful [A Qualitative and Quantitative Evaluation of 8 Clear Sky Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04336) I was going to mention an Astronomy SE question but realized that [you'd already answered it](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44921/7982)! :-)

Comment: Space SE's [Why does Unity look transparent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54083/12102) was down voted because of title but I think you can use results here to explain what's happening there as well.

Comment: Then was going to mention another Astronomy SE question but I see [you'd already answered it also](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43814/7982)!